# Baking zucchini bread without egg yolks

Tags: baking, egg-whites

I'm trying to reduce cholesterol in my diet and have switched to using egg whites (from a carton) instead of whole eggs.  This substitution usually works out OK, but when I make zucchini bread -- and other quick breads -- the loaves don't rise as well as they used to, and they tend to be drier.

I'm doing a 1:1 substitution using the guide on the carton (1egg is approx. 2oz), so I assume that a lot of the problem is that I'm missing the fat from the egg yolks.  Is this correct, and if so, what can I use instead that will be low in cholesterol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genetics is actually the greatest affect on cholesterol.  Consumption of dietary cholesterol has very little correlation to serum cholesterol in your body and the amount of cholesterol you're going to save by leaving out the egg yolks vs. the impact it has on the resulting bread will hardly be worth it.

However, if you wish to proceed then I'd recommedn simply adding about a tablespoon of vegetable oil in replacement of the egg yolks that are being omitted.

The fat in the egg yolks is going to assist in minimizing gluten development.  Since you've omitted the fat there is probably a bit more gluten formation taking place and thus the fact that it doesn't rise as well.  Egg whites have a drying effect on baked goods so that is why the bread is drier than before.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I just took a batch from the oven and it's a lot closer to how I remember it.  My original recipe called for 3 eggs (for 2 loaves), and I used 1 today, with flax seed (per Rebekah's answer) and egg white replacing the other two.  I also upped the amount of zucchini in the batter from 2 cups to 3 (per AttilaNYC).

Answer (score 2):

I've read that you can substitute 1 tablespoon ground flax seed mixed with three tablespoons of water for 1 egg quite successfully. [Here](http://www.vegcooking.com/vegcooking-eggreplace.asp) is a list of options containing that one.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this in the batch I made today and the results were promising.

Answer (score 1):

Smash up or blend about a half a banana or 1/4 cup applesauce to use as an egg replacer for each egg in baked goods such as muffins, pancakes or yeast-free quick breads, such as pumpkin bread, or your zucchini bread - they will add a good amount of thick moisture, like eggs, but they won't help your dishes rise, so include a bit of baking powder or baking soda to help it rise if needed.

Comment: I've done this in other recipes, but I decided to increase the amount of zucchini I use (it _is_ zucchini bread after all :).